# What is the location of this Application's file?

Tags: applications, applescript, launchd

This application shows in Finder at path (with target):

```
Macintosh HD/Applications/Trans_Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/applet
```

and I have not been able to successfully start it with `launchd`, using

```
~/Applications/Trans_Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/applet
//  or
/Users/myusername/Applications/Trans_Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/applet
```

Repeatedly seeing the following in console:

```
… com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[150] (com.mahogany.sarah[1156]): Job failed to exec(3). Setting up event to tell us when to try again: 2: No such file or directory
… com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[150] (com.mahogany.sarah[1156]): Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 2
… com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[150] (com.mahogany.sarah): Job should be able to exec(3) now.
```

So, I am concluding that the file is not referenced correctly.

In case it helps, the plist file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` looks like:

```
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mahogany.sarah</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>~/Applications/Trans_Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/applet</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>15</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>25</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

**EDIT: It finally worked using** suggested changes AND removing the tilde from before /Applications. (This is, incidentally, exactly what the Finder > File Info displays for the applet)

```
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mahogany.sarah</string>
    <key>Program</key>    // Change here and removing 1st char of string on next line
    <string>/Applications/Trans_Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/applet</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>15</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>25</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems with the above plist.

1. You've put the program in the `ProgramArguments` key.

   Replace the `ProgramArguments` key with the `Program` key and the array with a string.
2. You can't use `~` in a Launch Agent plist.

   Replace the `~` with the absolute path.

Comment: You're saying there should only be a Program key?

Comment: @David If you're not passing arguments, yes

Comment: Is `Program` key with a string value?

Comment: @David Yes, no array, just one string

Comment: Having `Program` as array results in `Invalid argument` upon launchclt load … The plist will load with `Program` key and string value.

Comment: It worked typing the program as `/Applications/Trans_Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/applet`. Notice the missing tilde or user's folder reference.  BUT WHY ??

Comment: @David If you've put the app there, then that's what the path will be. I can't correct your path as it depends entirely on where you've put the app.